# Get Count of Missing records between two tables (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables one for patient visit and another the visit lookup. I have patient visit from 10 to 70 in the look up table.

Some patients have missed visits in there regular schedule. Say a patient has come for visits 10, 20 , 30, 60 and 70. So 40 and 50 will be there missed visits.

I want to return patients who has missed visits.

I tried to left join and sub queries however its returning me only those records in the patient table.

Below is the query that i used and screenshot of my output.

```
SELECT Patient, vl.Visit, vl.VisitName FROM dbo.PatientVisit p LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Visitlookup vl ON p.VisitName = vl.VisitName
order BY p.Patient, vl.Visit


SELECT A.Patient, B.visit FROM 
(SELECT Patient, Visit, VisitName FROM dbo.PatientVisit)A, 
(SELECT Visit, VisitName FROM dbo.Visitlookup v1 WHERE v1.Visit NOT IN (SELECT Visit FROM dbo.PatientVisit v ))B
WHERE A.Visit <> B.Visit
```

[image: Left Join Output]

Can anyone help me in getting the patient numbers and the visits they missed?

Here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5824/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem

```
    SELECT A.Patient
       ,B.Visit
    FROM dbo.PatientVisit AS A
    INNER JOIN dbo.Visitlookup AS B ON NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                                                        FROM dbo.PatientVisit p1
                                                        WHERE A.Patient = p1.Patient
                                                          AND B.Visit = p1.Visit )
                                       AND A.Visit <> B.Visit
    GROUP BY A.Patient
       ,B.visit
    HAVING B.Visit <> MAX(A.Visit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get Missing Patient, Visit, VisitName from the Scheduled two tables from below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.Patient, v.Visit, v.VisitName
FROM PatientVisit AS p
CROSS JOIN  Visitlookup  AS v   
--WHERE p.Patient = 101
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT P.Patient, v.Visit, v.VisitName
FROM PatientVisit AS p
JOIN  Visitlookup  AS v 
    ON v.Visit = p.Visit
--WHERE p.Patient = 101
```

You can get the count of Missing Patient's Number of Visits from the below query:

```
SELECT p.Patient, COUNT(p.Visit) AS MissingVisitCount
FROM PatientVisit AS p
GROUP BY p.Patient
HAVING COUNT(p.Visit) != (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Visitlookup)
```

Hope these will be useful to you.